# Node.js, Protocol buffers - how to get the post payload so I can parse?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

Clients post protocol buffers to my url.  I need to get the payload to I can parse.  I am using express but I will take anything that works.

```
app.post('/n/bidder', function(req, res){

    var payload = ??????;

    var mypb_schema  = schema['Feeds'];
    var brr_fu = mypb_schema.parse(payload); 
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to receive the payload from the `req` input stream and combine the parts:

```
var buffertools = require('buffertools');

app.post('/n/bidder', function (req, res) {
  var payload = [];

  req.on('data', function (data) {
    payload.push(data);
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    var payload = buffertools.concat.apply(null, payload);

    var mypb_schema = schema['Feeds'];
    var brr_fu = mypb_schema.parse(payload);

    // rest of code here

  });

});
```